# Add Date of Report to Column using Power Query - Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, excelquery

Not sure if this will make sense. I have been Googling and trying to find the answer to this but cannot work it out, I am trying to add in a custom formula to the Power Query that will add in the date of the report to each row item within the report:

[Replacing the "Null" with the Report Name Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Z5o.png)

[This is the source and the last 8 characters are the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhN9R.png)

Does anyone have any clue on how to achieve this? I have been stuck on this for a few hours

Thanks,
Shea

Comment: Did any of the three answers help you? If so, you should toggle the checkmark on that answer to mark issue as solved and tick the up-arrow to give them a boost

Answer (score 1):

You could add a calculated column using:

```
=Date.FromText(Text.Start(Text.End(SourceFilePath, 14), 9)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StartOfMonthFilePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
mydate = Text.End(Text.BeforeDelimiter(path , ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}),9),
add = Table.AddColumn(NameOfYourTableHere, "NewColumnNameHere", each mydate)
in add
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you want.
First of all, the screenshot tagged with `This is the source` is actually showing the result of the preceding step.

And your screenshot of your table does not show where exactly you want the dates.

Assuming:

- The result of your `Previous File Path` step contains the desired date
- You want to replace `Column 1` nulls in your `PM Variance Report1` with that date

you can use the following code inserted after `PM Variance Report1`:

```
   #"Extract Date" = Date.From(Text.End(Text.BeforeDelimiter(#"Previous File Path",".",{0,RelativePosition.FromEnd}),9),"en-US"),
    #"Replace Col1 Nulls" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"PM Variance Report1",
        null,
        #"Extract Date",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"Column1"})
```

***Before***
[image]

***After***
[image]

You'll also need to change the code of your subsequent step (probable `Changed Type` to refer to `#"Replace Col1 Nulls"` step rather than `PM Variance Report 1`.